# Emergency Stop! Fatal Error Occurred in ShareLatex template report

Tags: pdftex, sharelatex, report, compilation-error

I am a newbie when it comes to LaTex and I was trying to modify a template in ShareLaTeX. As soon as I opened it, I got the following error (before compilation):

```
Emergency stop.

<*> preamble.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 19261 strings out of 492990
 348512 string characters out of 6132621
 430327 words of memory out of 5000000
 22497 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4709 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 62i,0n,56p,439b,287s stack positions out of 
 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Here is the code for preamble.tex for the ShareLaTeX project:

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5b7442e4686c0e6c29893613

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Language, Encoding and Fonts
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Select encoding of your inputs. Depends on
% your operating system and its default input
% encoding. Typically, you should use
%   Linux  : utf8 (most modern Linux distributions)
%            latin1 
%   Windows: ansinew
%            latin1 (works in most cases)
%   Mac    : applemac
% Notice that you can manually change the input
% encoding of your files by selecting "save as"
% an select the desired input encoding. 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Make latex understand and use the typographic
% rules of the language used in the document.
\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
% Use the vector font Latin Modern which is going
% to be the default font in latex in the future.
\usepackage{lmodern}
% Choose the font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Graphics and Tables
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% load a colour package
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{aaublue}{RGB}{33,26,82}% dark blue
% The standard graphics inclusion package
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Set up how figure and table captions are displayed
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
  font=footnotesize,% set font size to footnotesize
  labelfont=bf % bold label (e.g., Figure 3.2) font
}
% Make the standard latex tables look so much better
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
% Enable the use of frames around, e.g., theorems
% The framed package is used in the example environment
\usepackage{framed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mathematics
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Defines new environments such as equation,
% align and split 
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Adds new math symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
% Use theorems in your document
% The ntheorem package is also used for the example environment
% When using thmmarks, amsmath must be an option as well. Otherwise         \eqref doesn't work anymore.
\usepackage[framed,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page Layout
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Change margins, papersize, etc of the document
\usepackage[
  left=28mm,% left margin on an odd page
  right=41mm,% right margin on an odd page
  ]{geometry}
% Modify how \chapter, \section, etc. look
% The titlesec package is very configureable
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{aaublue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{aaublue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}        {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{aaublue}}
%\titleformat*{\paragraph}    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{aaublue}}
%\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{aaublue}}

% Change the headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %delete everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the horizontal line in the     header
\fancyhead[RE]{\color{aaublue}\small\nouppercase\leftmark} %even page - chapter title
\fancyhead[LO]{\color{aaublue}\small\nouppercase\rightmark} %uneven page - section title
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} %page number on all pages
% Do not stretch the content of a page. Instead,
% insert white space at the bottom of the page
\raggedbottom
% Enable arithmetics with length. Useful when
% typesetting the layout.
\usepackage{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Add the \citep{key} command which display a
% reference as [author, year]
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
% Appearance of the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Misc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Add bibliography and index to the table of
% contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
% Add the command \pageref{LastPage} which refers to the
% page number of the last page
\usepackage[
%  disable, %turn off todonotes
  colorinlistoftodos, %enable a coloured square in the list of todos
  textwidth=\marginparwidth, %set the width of the todonotes
  textsize=scriptsize, %size of the text in the todonotes
  ]{todonotes}
% added by KK (ShareLaTeX team)
\usepackage{lastpage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hyperlinks
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Enable hyperlinks and insert info into the pdf
% file. Hypperref should be loaded as one of the 
% last packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    %pdfpagelabels=true,%
    plainpages=false,%
    pdfauthor={Author(s)},%
    pdftitle={Title},%
    pdfsubject={Subject},%
    bookmarksnumbered=true,%
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=aaublue,%
    filecolor=aaublue,%
    linkcolor=aaublue,% you should probably change this to black before printing
    urlcolor=aaublue,%
    pdfstartview=FitH%
}
```

Please let me know how to fix it, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Unfortunately, the link requires a login.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The sharleatex website requires to log in. Can you try to post the code here? (Edit your question and copy & paste the code here.)

Comment: Don't use a complex template when you are newbie. Start with a simple document. And don't expect people to debug a project on another site, even more if a login is required.

Comment: Well the error message says the truth: the document has no legal end command, there is no \end{document} (and also no \begin{document}). You can't compile this unless you add a document body.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer after adding \begin{document} and \end{document} I get a "PDF Rendering Error: Something went wrong while rendering this PDF."

Comment: Did you add any contents within begin/end document? For example the word hello.

Comment: @daleif Yes, then hello is all it shows. All the remaining content in the repository does not compile.